# What MySQL executes first: SELECT or HAVING?

Tags: mysql

I'm quite novice in MySQL and while learning GROUP BY/HAVING I've faced this query:

```
SELECT author_id, COUNT(author_id) FROM posts GROUP BY author_id HAVING COUNT(author_id) > 2;
```

I've found an article about SQL's execution order which says that the sequence looks like this:

> FROM clause ->
>   WHERE clause ->
>   GROUP BY clause ->
>   HAVING clause ->
>   SELECT clause ->
>   ORDER BY clause

But if it is so, how can the next query be executed successfully?

```
SELECT author_id, COUNT(author_id) AS posts_count 
    FROM posts 
    GROUP BY author_id 
    HAVING posts_count > 2;
```

How can `HAVING` know about "posts_count" alias, if `SELECT` executes after `HAVING`? Is the information, that I found, incorrect or this is some kind of MySQL's specific behavior that differs from SQL standard?

Also, if `HAVING` uses "`posts_count`" alias from `SELECT` in the second query, I can make a wild guess that `HAVING` won't run `COUNT()` again to filter groups and will just take necessary data from "post_count" column. But than, will `HAVING` do the same thing in the first query or it will run `COUNT()` twice (first one in `SELECT` and second on in `HAVING`) for each group, making query execution time longer?

I'm sorry for possibly calling some things with wrong names, I'm only in the beginnig of learning MySQL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the execution order is:

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

The thing is that if you run your query with alias will be invalid in T-SQL (SQL Server) because HAVING is referring to the SELECT alias posts_count.

However, In MySQL is different. MySQL extends standard SQL behavior to permit the use of an alias in the HAVING clause for the aggregated column.

Check the last example here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, this is exactly what I've been looking for!